# I want to be able to upload a batch of tweets to a twitter bot to be qued' for tweeting

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, c++, ethernet

I have built a twitter bot with my Arduino and an Ethernet shield
right now, the way to make it tweet something is to manually add a phase into the code and upload it to the board for each new tweet,

I would like to create a simple way of scrolling through a queue of phrases and tweeting each consecutive one after a given amount of time (several hours).
the issue I'm seeing is that, the code needs to rerun for each tweet, and I can't figure out what needs to be in what loop. Also the entire thing needs to delay for 3.6e^6(1 hour) milliseconds (the code takes delays in milliseconds) so that I don't spam the feed, 
the twitter for this project is @ether_bot.

Code is below:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <Twitter.h>

/*
void speech()
{
  //this is where i would put the que of tweets
}
*/

// the next three lines connect the ethernet shield to the local network and establish a link with the twitter account
byte ip[] = { 192,168,1,104 }; 
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xEU }; //address for the shield
Twitter twitter("2790106893-5ljE7WPyyGe16SqTMEm8CN5gpwDquhGnyjH2TCM"); 
char msg[] = "hello again, im getting some major work done soon!"; // message to tweet

void setup()
{
  delay(30000);
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);  // makes the connection 
  Serial.begin(9600); //opens a serial interface similar to the prnt window in bluejay
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.println("connecting ...");

  if (twitter.post(msg)) 
  {
    int status = twitter.wait();

    if (status == 200)
    { 
      Serial.println("OK.");
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.print("failed : code ");  //stuff happens here idk 
      Serial.println(status);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("connection failed.");
  }

  do {} while(1);
}
```

Comment: You mention a "queue" of messages; a queue has to be fed somehow: how would it be fed in your situation? If it is static, then it is not really a queue and the problem is rather simple to solve (see @geometrikal answer below).

Comment: i would like the next tweet in the queue to be tweeted after a certain amount of time, (say every few hours)

Comment: You did not answer my question: is the lsit of tweets in the queue "static", ie known and fixed at compile-time, or is it dynamic, ie it can change at runtime; in the latter cas, how is the queue fed with new tweets?

Comment: static. the tweets would be typed in before the compile. i would generate all of them myself and they would all be in the code from the beginning. after the tweets in the queue are all tweeted, then i would type new ones into the code and re-upload

Comment: Ok. Then @geometrikal answer fits your question.

Answer (score 1):

First create an array of all the messages:

```
#define NUM_MESSAGES 3
const char *msg[NUM_MESSAGES] = { 
    "This is the first message", 
    "This is the second",
    "Third time lucky" };
int msg_num = 0;
```

Then in the loop, switch between messages and add a delay

```
void loop()
{
  Serial.println("connecting ...");
  if (twitter.post(*msg[msg_num])) 
  {
    int status = twitter.wait();
    if (status == 200)
    { 
      Serial.println("OK.");
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.print("failed : code ");  //stuff happens here idk 
      Serial.println(status);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("connection failed.");
  }

  //Next message
  msg_num++;
  if (msg_num >= NUM_MESSAGES) msg_num = 0;
  delay(1000*60*60);
}
```

Comment: so i put some stuff together and got this error at this line... im a totatl noob at coding so i dont really know how to make it work,,,,


  if (twitter.post(*msg[msg_num])) 

sketch_oct06a.ino: In function 'void loop()':
sketch_oct06a:18: error: invalid conversion from 'const char' to 'const char*'
sketch_oct06a:18: error: initializing argument 1 of 'bool Twitter::post(const char*)'

Comment: Try removing the `*` in front of `*msg[msg_num]`. This now compiles for me but I don't have a WiFi/Ethernet shield to test it.